# Latex Presentation: letting bullets appear

Tags: beamer

I am using latex to create a document in the beamer class. Say I have a frame with three bullets. In order to keep the attention of my public, I would like to start with only the first bullet and then advance to the next two bullets by letting them appear after I click on the mouse/pointer. In Powerpoint I would do this by using one slide and letting the additional bullets appear via the appearance option.

However, the only way I can think of to do this in Latex, is making three different frames: one with one bullet, the second with two bullets and the third with three bullets. This is unhandy and furthermore (I am using `\usetheme{Darmstadt}`) every frame is given a different circle in the contents in the upper part of the frame, such that I get way too many circles.

Any smart ways to resolve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or you can specify how show each item:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Darmstadt}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Only one frame}
\begin{enumerate}
\item<1-> One bullet
\item<3> One more  bullet
\item<2-> Another  bullet   
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: How can I use this method to start with an empty frame and then get the first bullet after I click?

Comment: @Funzies Of course, put `\pause` before of the enumerate environment.

Comment: Thanks! But if I use the code 
\pause
\begin{itemize}
\item<1->{Text1}
\vspace{0.4 cm}
\item<2->{Text2}
\end{itemize}, then indeed there are no bullets to start with, but after clicking both bullets appear at once..

Comment: @Funzies, yes, because after `\pause` you are *in the second slide*, so both `<1->` (first and the following slides) and `<2->` (second slide and the following) appeared. Solution: use `\item<2->` for the first item.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `\beamerdefaultoverlayspecification`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{<+->}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item A thing.
\item Another thing.
\item And another thing.
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

There are lots of ways to control this type of effect; it's probably best to consult the relevant sections of the [beamer package documentation](http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer) for more details.